# Displaying JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following array

```
"forecast":{
    "txt_forecast": {
    "date":"11:00 PM EDT",
    "forecastday": [
    {
    "period":0,
    "icon":"partlycloudy",
    "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
    "title":"Saturday",
    "fcttext":"Partly cloudy in the morning, then mostly cloudy. High of 88F. Winds from the South at 5 to 10 mph.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy in the morning, then mostly cloudy. High of 31C. Winds from the South at 10 to 15 km/h.",
    "pop":"0"
    }
    ,
    {
    "period":1,
    "icon":"partlycloudy",
    "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
    "title":"Saturday Night",
    "fcttext":"Overcast in the evening, then partly cloudy. Low of 64F. Winds less than 5 mph.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Overcast in the evening, then partly cloudy. Low of 18C. Winds less than 5 km/h.",
    "pop":"10"
    }
```

How would I display the information in PHP? It goes all the way up to period 7.

EDIT: Here is my edited code that is not working.

```
<?php
$json_string =    file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/7ec5f6510a4656df/geolookup/forecast/q/40121.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$temp = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'date'};
$title = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}->{'title'};
$for = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}->{'fcttext'};
echo "Current date is ${temp},  ${title}: ${for}\n";

foreach($parsed_json['forecast']['forecastday[0]'] as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['period'];
   echo $value['icon'];
   // etc
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that your JSON is invalid: you need to surround it in `{ }`, or remove `"forecast": `. Plus, you never close your square brackets.

Comment: Looks like you want the alternate form of decoding: my answer

Comment: Note that `$parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}->{'fcttext'}` is equivalent to `$parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday->fcttext`

Comment: I guess im missing what you mean on this.. Could you show me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update

```
$json_string =    file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/7ec5f6510a4656df/geolookup/forecast/q/40121.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$parsed_json = $parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'];
//pr($parsed_json);

foreach($parsed_json as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['period'] . '<br>';
   echo $value['icon'] . '<br>';
   // etc
}
```

**Result:**

```
0
chancetstorms
1
tstorms
2
tstorms
3
tstorms
4
tstorms
5
partlycloudy
6
partlycloudy
7
partlycloudy
```

---

You will have to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function for that.

```
$myArray = json_decode($yourJSON, true);
```

Now you can use `foreach` to get the data from `$myArray` array eg:

```
foreach($myArray['forecast']['forecastday'] as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['period'];
   echo $value['icon'];
   // etc
}
```

Comment: @Eric: To convert it to an array and that's my personal preference :)

Comment: @DavidMorin: See updated answer plz. You did not provide correct json start point in your question first :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert json to PHP objects:

```
$myData = json_decode($yourJSON);

foreach($myData->forecast->forecastday as $day) {
   echo $day->period;
   echo $day->icon;
}
```

---

### EDIT:

I think you can fix the code in your question with this:

```
<?php
$json_string =    file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/7ec5f6510a4656df/geolookup/forecast/q/40121.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$forecast = $parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast;
$temp = $forecast->date;
$title = $forecast->forecastday->title;
$for = $forecast->forecastday->fcttext;
echo "Current date is ${temp},  ${title}: ${for}\n";

foreach($forecast->forecastday as $value) {
   echo $value['period'];
   echo $value['icon'];
   // etc
}
?>
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @DavidMorin: What does `print_r($myData->forecast->forecastday)` give?

Comment: @DavidMorin: What about `print_r($myData->forecast)`?

Comment: with your above edit i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in

Comment: @DavidMorin: Missing semicolon

Comment: lol almost there  now Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12353/discussion-between-david-morin-and-eric)

Comment: @DavidMorin: See the chat: you were traversing over the wrong bit of the json